# File I/O in D programming language

Tags: d, dmd

I'm trying to follow a simple tutorial and can't get the following code to work:

```
void main(string args[])
{
  auto f = File("test.txt", "w");
  f.writeln("Hello, Worlds!");
}
```

I'm using the dmd compiler on windows.

Comment: Why not?

Does the program crash?  Does the program merely not work correctly?

Does compilation fail?  Does the compiler *crash*?  Do you know that the compiler is installed correctly?  What version of the language are you using?

Comment: Compilation fails. I'm using D2, I think. The compilation error is:
(5): Error: unidentified identifier file
(5): Error: function expected before (), not __error of type _error_
(6): Error: function expected before (), not __error of type TOK149

Answer (score 18):

If you are using D2, you need to `import std.stdio;`:

```
import std.stdio;
void main(string args[])
{
  auto f = File("test.txt", "w");
  f.writeln("Hello, Worlds!");
}
```

If you are using D1, the `File` class is in `std.stream`, and the API is slightly different:

```
import std.stream;
void main() {
  auto f = new File("test.txt", FileMode.Out);
  f.writeLine("Hello, Worlds!");
}
```